# How to save create global variables (with custom name) in a private function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm creating an algebra math tool where I take an equation, take the terms, pair like terms, and then evaluate. (I'm making this as a coding exercise)

For the equation `a + b - 2a` I've gotten the terms saved in an array; ["+a", "+b", "-2a"]. Now what I want is to change this into this:

```
var lTERMa = ["+a", "-2a"];
var lTERMb = ["+b"];
```

So far my "fix" is to store the variables in a div element that has white text so you can't see it. It's rather crude, and it doesn't work. Here is the full Javascript code that I've made designed to store them in the div:

```
function appendinformation(info) {
document.getElementById("hiddenData").innerHTML += info;
}
function runData(bool, int) {
if (bool) {
  eval(document.getElementById("hiddenData").innerHTML)
  console.log()
}
eval(document.getElementById("hiddenData").innerHTML)
}


var termsViewed = 0;
var lTermsFound = 0;
var seenTerms = []
function processTERMpos(val) {
  if (seenTerms.includes(val.replaceAll("+", ""))) {
    termsViewed++;
    appendinformation(`var lLTERM${val.replaceAll("+", "")} = [${val}]`);
    runData()
  }
  if (!seenTerms.includes(val.replaceAll("+", ""))) {
    appendinformation(`lTERM${val.replaceAll("+", "")}.push(${val})`)
    runData()
    seenTerms.push(val.replaceAll("+", ""))
    lTermsFound++;
    termsViewed++;
  }
}
function processTERMneg(val) {
  if (seenTerms.includes(val.replaceAll("-", ""))) {
    termsViewed++;
    appendinformaion(`var lLTERM${val.replaceAll("-", "")} = [${val}]`);
    runData()
  }
  if (!seenTerms.includes(val.replaceAll("-", ""))) {
    appendinformation(`lTERM${val.replaceAll("-", "")}.push(${val})`)
    runData()
    seenTerms.push(val.replaceAll("-", ""))
    lTermsFound++;
    termsViewed++;
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
  var subject = term[i]
  getHiddenData();
  eval(hdata);
  if (subject.includes("+")) {processTERMpos(subject)}
  if (subject.includes("-")) {processTERMpos(subject)}
}
```

Don't bully me for my bad disorganised coding. I've deleted and reinstated various code, and I'm sure there is code in there than no longer has a use.

If someone could either fix my code, or be able to suggest another way for me to attempt rewriting the code. I've been deleting and rewriting this code for 2 hours and I can't think of any way I can fix it.

Comment: change `appendinformation(`var lLTERM${val.replaceAll("+", "")} = [${val}]`);` with `appendinformation(`var lLTERM${val.replaceAll("+", "")} = [${val}];`);` and replace `appendinformation(`lTERM${val.replaceAll("-", "")}.push(${val})`)` with `appendinformation(`lTERM${val.replaceAll("-", "")}.push(${val});`)` Just added semicolan.

Comment: I think you mean to call `processTERMneg` here `if (subject.includes("-")) {processTERMpos(subject)}`

Comment: If I'm not wrong your `runData()` is just taking html from `hiddenData` and evaluating it. Which means it just create unique Array and push other data in it?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, it means alot.